# Generate only parent taxonomy terms in a block

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I need to generate a menu for parent taxonomy terms.

How would I go about doing this? I'm also looking to generate these terms in a block.

I have a views set up right now that displays just all taxonomy terms. I can't figure out how to filter out child terms. Is there a filter for this, or do I just have to manually create each category item?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Drupal 7 to only show parent terms you add a “Contextual Filter” and add “Taxonomy term: Parent term,” then set “Provide default value” to a “fixed value” of 0.

That will filter out the child terms.

Answer (score 8):

You can just add a normal filter, set the "Parent term" filter to "0", that does the same as the contextual filter with "provide default value" as mentioned above. Turns out the root terms have a parent of 0 which I only just found out thanks to this post :)

Comment: Both have the same outcome, this is much quicker.